# How to iterate callable statement cursor in Java 1.6

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, callable-statement

I'm using Java 1.6 and SQL Server stored procedure in my application. And I don't know to retrieve data from the stored procedure. In JDK 1.7 we can use OracleTypes.CURSOR but I don't know how to retrieve in CURSOR and iterate in 1.6

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: why do you want to use 1.6, what's wrong with 1.8?

Comment: Its an old application and they are using 1.6..

Comment: You will get a resultSet which you can use to iterate the ResultSet. Check the java docs :- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html

Comment: Thanks. Its working :)